# Word Highlight color macro

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am trying to create a simple button which changes the color of the Default Highlight color in word. Below is the code I am using. For some reason the color is not changing when I click the button.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Options.DefaultHighlightColorIndex = wdRed
End Sub
```

Comment: The code you posted is incomplete and it's impossible to know whether whatever button you're referring to is calling it correctly.

Comment: This is the entire code I am using and there is only one button in the document. I have double clicked on the button and added the second line of the code.

Comment: The code has been edited since I posted. There is nothing wrong with the edited code; it works as it should. If, for example, you do a Find/Replace with the 'highlight' option for the replacement, the replaced content will have a red highlight. The button selection on the Ribbon is not changed.